# I do not drip ruby life juice

Tags: riddle, wordplay

**I am pretty prehistoric, but not extinct,**

**it would be hard to miss me if I blinked.**

**I do not drip ruby life juice,**

**and my tail is even pointer than that of a mongoose.**

**You might think I am the lucky one,**

**but it is you who benefits when all is said and done.**

Happy Monday, riddle away! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a:

> Horseshoe crab

I am pretty prehistoric, but not extinct,

> Horseshoe crabs are one of the oldest species still extant

it would be hard to miss me if I blinked.

> From Wikipedia: 'the animals have the largest rods and cones of any known animal, about 100 times the size of humans'

I do not drip ruby life juice,

> Horseshoe crab blood is blue

and my tail is even pointer than that of a mongoose.

> Horseshoe crabs have a notoriously pointy tail

You might think I am the lucky one, but it is you who benefits when all is said and done.

> Horseshoe crab blood is farmed for use in numerous medical therapies.

Comment: Haha very good! I did not think anybody would get it that fast. Horseshoe crabs are quite amazing creatures and have greatly helped out in the medical field, especially with current events. The third clue referred to the fact that they have 10 eyes, but you were very close.

Comment: I lived by the Chesapeake Bay for many years, and used to see them all the time, sadly decreasingly often. Normally I'm pretty bad at riddles, but this was in my wheelhouse :-)

Comment: Nice! My career is built around using their blood to help ensure medical devices and products are clean, along with their conservation!

Comment: Awesome! Keep up the good work, friend!

Comment: Thank you, keep up that riddle answering! :D